# yasnippets and org-mode: yas-next-field-or-maybe-expand does not expand

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet

In org mode, the TAB key maps to yas-next-field-or-maybe-expand. But it is not working.

But if I run yas-expand (by hand) it works as expected.

TAB does expand in other modes.

Any ideas what might be wrong with my configuration? where to start debugging my (long) startup configuration?

thanks a lot!

Comment: What org version are you using? Have you set `org-src-tab-acts-natively` and/or `org-src-fontify-natively`? See also https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem for a long time, sometimes tab worked well, sometimes it didn't. Finally, the solution for me was to.. follow advice from org-mode manual! [Here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Conflicts.html), in the section about conflicts with packages, under **yasnippet.el** paragraph there's an explanation:

> The way Org mode binds the  key (binding to [tab] instead of "\t") overrules YASnippet's access to this key.

And below there are two ways to fix it, the second approach worked for me, here's the code (updated to remove deprecated stuff):

```
(defun yas-org-very-safe-expand ()
  (let ((yas-fallback-behavior 'return-nil)) (yas-expand)))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (add-to-list 'org-tab-first-hook 'yas-org-very-safe-expand)
        (define-key yas-keymap [tab] 'yas-next-field)))
```

For it to work it might be necessary to re-load org-mode, so the hook gets called.

As @npostavs suggested, it's useful to mention that this solution works for org-mode version 9.1.2 and yasnippet version 0.12.2.

Comment: `yas-trigger-key` is by now also long obsolete, and setting it won't do anything.

Comment: @npostavs I edited the code to remove the lines about `yas-trigger-key` and I checked that restarting my Emacs without this code results in tabs not working, and with this code they work correctly, so it seems to do the job. does it look ok to you now?

Comment: It would be useful to list which org and yasnippet versions this works in. I had yasnippet working nicely with org when setting `org-src-tab-acts-natively` and `org-src-fontify-natively`,  but it doesn't work with the latest 9.x org, unfortunately (ref [#852](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/852)). Perhaps your approach would be more robust to changes in org.

Comment: thank you very much. It solved the problem i was having. I appreciate the time you took to write the answer.